# How i can render a template and then redirect to particular URL in Django?

Tags: django, url, redirect, registration

i've a problem with django views. I have a URL **/signup.html** that have a view and display a form. The action of this form points to **/account/create** so when everything it's ok i do a redirect to congrats page, but when the form submitted it's invalid, i need to back to the last url with a dictionary of errors but when i do render_to_response the url in the address bar it's **account/create** and should **/signup.html**.

Here is the code:

```
def signup(request):
    return render_to_response('main/signup.html' , {} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def create_account(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FastSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return redirect('/account/congratulations' , {} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = FastSignupForm();

    return render_to_response('main/signup.html', {'form':form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def congrats(request):
    return render_to_response('main/congrats.html', {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What i'm doing wrong ?

**EDIT:**
If i post over the same url (signup.html), when a i reload the page i've multiple post submits and i want to prevent this.

Comment: You didn't copy/paste this did you? I noticed that you have a semi-colon after `form = FastSignupForm()`

Comment: Maybe but it's very irrelevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

Why not post to the same URL (signup.html) then only redirect when successful?

Comment: If i post over the same url (signup.html), when a i reload the page i've multiple post submits and i want to prevent this.

Comment: @Agusti-N Unfortunately, it's difficult to try to redirect URLs with the dictionary of errors.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters/3210919#3210919

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you need to go to `/account/create`. Can't you just do this:

**views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FastSignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            return redirect('/account/congratulations' , {} , 
                         context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = FastSignupForm();

    return render_to_response('main/signup.html', {'form':form} , 
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def congrats(request):
    return render_to_response('main/congrats.html', {}, 
                 context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**main/signup.html**

```
...
<form method="post" action=".">
    ...
</form>
...
```

I'm not sure if you really need to go to `create_account()` or not, but if you don't this should work for you.

Comment: "If i post over the same url (signup.html), when a i reload the page i've multiple post submits and i want to prevent this."

Comment: I don't understand... he'll have multiple post submits anyway if the form isn't valid. Just in his case, he'll have an extra step of redirecting