# django - redisplay a form after postback but as unbound

Tags: django, forms

Still new to python and django, though learning ;-)

I have a view that is intended to display a form with contact information. After succesfully processing the form and saving/creating the object, I want to display the same view again (to add another contact) but with a message added saying the previous contact information was successfully saved.

From [Django return redirect() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters) I learned that the way to redirect to a view with a passed parameter is to simply call the view again and display the response.

My view starts as follows:

```
def addabentry(request, entrytype, messages=[]):
""" Presents form to create a company listing, then enters company into database"""
```

After postback and successfully saving the data, I call the view again as follows:

```
messages = ["%s %s has been added." % (entrytype, entry.name)]
response = addabentry(request, entrytype=entrytype, messages=messages)
return HttpResponse(response)
```

However, the form on the second go-round seems to be bound with the previous data, presumably because the POST parameter is still in the request object I pass to the view.

Is there a way to unbind the form for the second time around?  Or, as is more likely, is there a better way of doing what I want? Do I need to use request.sessions as mentioned in the referenced SO question?

Thanks for your help!

W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) framework.

Comment: Yup, also maybe some forsmets to allow multiple contacts forms be dynamically loaded on the page (using javascript maybe): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: Thanks! Will also look into messages/sessions

Comment: Having investigated the messages framework more, it does seem to be a better solution. Have changed the accepted answer accordingly.  THanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think you may be making things a lot more complicated than they need to.

from the basic form example in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

```
def contact(request):
    message = ''
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            # instead of redirecting here, create a new blank form, and add a message
            form = ContactForm()
            message = "contact successfully created"
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('contact.html', {
        'form': form,
        'message': message,
    })
```

Comment: My goodness. That is SO obvious (now that its pointed out!). Thanks!

Comment: @Westerley Yeah, that's really good if you like to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: the messages framework is great for messages across multiple pages (e.g. after redirects). since this case stays on the same page, using the messages framework may be overkill

Comment: @second What can be overkill? Storing messages in cookies?

Comment: @second And BTW using POST forms without redirecting on success isn't very good idea.

Comment: @DrTyrsa - its not apparent to me (python/django neophyte) why its not a good idea to use a POST form without redirecting; could you please explain?  Thanks!

Comment: actually, i think i agree. it would be better to redirect (in this case, to the same page). in which case you need to store the message somewhere else (users's session) and should probably use the messages framework as suggested

Comment: Ok, - but for the sake of education, WHY should you redirect after a POST form? Thanks!

Comment: For example, to allow a page refresh after the post without re-posting the previous data

Comment: I've updated the accepted answer accordingly, having looked into the messages framework