# Django, csrf_token does not appear on form after redirection

Tags: django

I am using this middleware to redirect all pages to a landing page: (part of `AuthRequiredMiddleware` class.

```
def process_request(self, request):
    assert hasattr(request, 'user') 
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        if path not in ['ipn/', 'pp_cancel/', 'pp_success/', 'sitemap/', 'welcome/']:
            lang = request.GET.get('lang', 'en')
            ru = request.GET.get('ru', '')
            return render_to_response('landing_en.html', RequestContext(request, {'ru': ru}))
```

and this is my `settings.py`

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (                                                                                                                                                                                   
     'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
     'main.common.SessionBasedLocaleMiddleware.SessionBasedLocaleMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'main.common.tz_middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',
     'main.common.sslMiddleware.SSLRedirect',
     'main.common.RedirectAllMiddleware.AuthRequiredMiddleware',
)
```

if the url is (for example) `/welcome/` and no redirection is performed `{% csrf_token %}` works and shows in the form. If user is redirected no csrf_token is shown in the form.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe that's part of the protection csrf provides (the main issue being cross site forgery, someone pretending to be the user but coming from a different url). I'm not sure how to translate this to a solution but try maybe using `render` instead of `render_to_response`. It makes sure all context processors will work correctly, so maybe that'll help

Comment: This is not a redirect! [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) is a redirect.

Comment: ``RequestContext(request, {'ru': ru})`` contains the csrf_token?

Comment: As an alternative to @yuvi (and I'm similarly not 100% sure about the definite functioning), your middleware returns a response using the `process_request` function while the `CsrdViewMiddleware` uses a [`process_view` middleware](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/csrf.py#L104) which may not be called if `process_request` has already started a response

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony csrf context processor is one of the standard processors, and it must be added by default in RequestContext ``__init__`` method

Comment: @yuvi `render` does not work either.

Comment: When using `requests` library to do a POST request on a django application you need to pass something called `Referrer` (simply a url of the page you're coming from). You might need to do something similar here

Comment: for debugging purposes, into your middleware, can you `print request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"]`  ?  Also, what about to move to a real redirect? This will add right referrer.

Comment: @danihp: I get this: `Exception Type: KeyError at / Exception Value: 'CSRF_COOKIE'`. The reason I am not using a real redirect is because I would like to render the landing page with a set of template variables. Now it is just 'ru' but will need to add more in the future.

Comment: "a set of template variables" - using a real redirect does not prevent any of that, and as @danihp mentioned will add the right referrer (which may very well be the problem)

Comment: as @yuvi explains, the view is the natural place where fill template variables. Render a page in your middleware is dirty. Take a look to [login_required decorator code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7477a4ffde4781f4e84503e66d7f775074089887/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py#L41), it make a redirect to login page. This will be the right approach  (... in my opinion, of course ...) .

Comment: @yuvi, thanks. But how am I supposed to `HttpResponseRedirect` and at the same time pass template variables?

Comment: There's more than one way. You can use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views), but it will be much easier to pass them [through the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters) either with a template regex or as GET data (if there's nothing sensitive in there of course)

Comment: @yuvi, thanks. Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Please make sure that works before you mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) about CSRF:

> Cross-site request forgery, also known as a one-click attack or
>   session riding [...]  is a type of malicious exploit of a website
>   whereby unauthorized commands are transmitted from a user that the
>   website trusts.

and later, under prevention:

> Verifying that the request's header contains a X-Requested-With (used
>   by Ruby on Rails before v2.0 and Django before v1.2.5), or checking
>   the HTTP Referer header and/or HTTP Origin header.

So actually, your csrf protection is working well. Because, while I'm not 100% that the problem is specifically the missing referrer, I do think that it's caused by not using a proper redirect which triggers a csrf violation.

The solution - use `HttpResponseRedirect` and pass the information to the other view. You can pass it as GET data:

```
 d = {'ru': ru, 'other': 'variables'}
 url = '/landing/?%' % '&'.join( map(lambda x: '='.join(x), d.items()) )
 return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

You can also use regex patterns in the urls (if that makes sense) or use [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) if there's anything sensitive in there.

Comment: Yes, it works. I also managed to pass template variables, too. Thanks!