# Sending a parameter to a view

Tags: python, django, django-views

Basically after a post, I want to re-render another view and send it a parameter, but I still want to direct it to the correct url. I do not want to use url parameters like **/?confirm=true**

url:

```
url(r'^$', 'index', name='home'),

def index(request, confirm=None):
    return ...
```

Im trying to send index view the parameter confirm=True

```
return redirect('home', kwargs={'confirm':True})
```

So this does not work, because the kwargs want to match the URL patter with /confirm/, but I dont want to do that, Im just trying to send some value to a view and render that view from another view.

Comment: What do you mean, "direct it to the correct URL"? Do you mean you want to keep the same URL as the page you posted to, or the normal URL of the place you're redirecting to?

Comment: I dont want to render the view with the url posted to, i want to render the original url, or where the post came from

Comment: have you consider using ajax?

Comment: Nope, I dont want to use it at the moment, but perhaps later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to pass a parameter in the URL, you need to pass it in some other way. The only real way to do this is to use the session: set a session variable in the post view, and check it in the index one.

```
def process_post(request, ...):
    ... do whatever ...
    request.session['confirm'] = True
    return redirect('home')


def index(request):
    confirm = request.session.pop('confirm', None)
    if confirm:
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand the question. Are you essentially trying to do this?

```
(r'^your_app_view/(?P<app_value>.+)/$',views.your_view)
```

then in your_view you can access app_value do whatever you need and redirect to another view.

Are you then asking how to get that argument to the second view that the first view is calling?

If so then this SO answer should help you.  [Django return redirect() with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters)

Comment: Look at my url patern, it takes no arguments