# redirect() not passing arguments to view Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm having trouble with `redirect()` in my Django views.

I have two views defined as follows:

```
# view for managing a user's account
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def view_account(request, updated=False):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'cart_items': ShoppingCartItem.objects.filter(user_key=request.user),
        'updated': updated,
    }
    print("DEBUG: view_account: %s" % updated)    # debug
    return render(request, 'registration/view_account.html', context)
```

and

```
# view for updating information about a user's account
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def update_account_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # if this is a POST, user has submitted updated information
        form = UpdateUserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            # if valid, redirect to view_account
            form.save()
            # return render(request, 'registration/view_account.html', context)
            return redirect('/view_account', updated=True)
```

My url's for these functions look like so:

```
path('view_account', views.view_account, name='view_account'),
path('update_account', views.update_account_info, name='update_account'),
```

In the second function, I'm trying to redirect the user to the `view_account()` view and pass in the `updated=True` argument to notify the user on the page that their information has been updated. For some reason when I run this, it does not seem to be changing the default value of `updated`.

As you can see, I've got a debug statement in the `view_account()` view. Output is as follows:

```
[04/Nov/2019 16:51:33] "POST /update_account HTTP/1.1" 302 0
DEBUG: view_account: False
[04/Nov/2019 16:51:33] "GET /view_account HTTP/1.1" 200 1247
```

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Can somebody spot something funny with my code and/or point me in the direction to look?

Thanks in advance! Also, I apologize if this isn't a well formatted question, I'm pretty new to StackOverflow so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to modify your urls. They should look like this:

```
path('view_account/(?P<updated>\d+)/$', views.view_account, name='view_account'),
path('update_account', views.update_account_info, name='update_account'),
```

this way your url will expect a parameter to be passed to the view_account view.
Here is a similar answer i found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23932182/12321427

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually just found a different solution where I use the `messages` module to display messages (which is what I was going for anyway). But I will mark your answer as the solution as it answers the original problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, the `messages` module does exactly what I was trying to do. Using it, I can save messages per request and have them displayed in the next view that uses it.

My solution is as follows.

My `update_account_info` view:

```
# view for updating information about a user's account
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
def update_account_info(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # if this is a POST, user has submitted updated information
        form = UpdateUserInfoForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            # if valid, redirect to view_account and re-login the user
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "User information updated!")
            return redirect('/view_account')
```

My `view_account` view:

```
# view for managing a user's account
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['GET'])
def view_account(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'cart_items': ShoppingCartItem.objects.filter(user_key=request.user),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/view_account.html', context)
```

My `view_account.html` template:

```
{% block messages %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li {% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %} {# for message #}
    {% endif %} {# if messages #}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope someone else finds this helpful!