# Django redirects for incomplete urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I have an Django application that has content at the url: /analyze/plot/123abc (or some other alphanumeric key).

I want to redirect anything that is just /analyze/plot/ to a predetermined url with a default key (such as /analyze/plot/a1). I would also like to redirect to this same url if any bad key is attempted for a url.

Here is what my url configuration looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('plot/', views.plot_redirect, name='plot_redirect'),
    path('plot/<graph_id>/', views.plot, name='plot'),
]
```

Views:

```
def plot_redirect(request):
    return redirect('analyze:plot:a1')

def plot(request, graph_id):
    """

    :param request: HTML request object
    :return: The html page
    """

    graph = get_object_or_404(pk=graph_id)
```

When I currently go to /analyze/plot I get an error.

Comment: You could unify to 1 view that accepts a single parameter `graph_id`, then test the validity / find a nearest match for that value within that view's code

Comment: Put "a1" to `args` instead of pattern name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ivan in an above comment, I had to modify my plot_redirect view to properly pass the argument.

```
def plot_redirect(request):
    return redirect('analyze:plot', graph_id='a1')
```