# Posting product quantity in a Django form

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm working with an e-commerce webapp and in the product detailed-view I want to give the option to set the quantity before the checkout. I thought I could do this with a simple form:

```
class QuantityForm(forms.Form):
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'required'}))
```

And then implementing it to the view:

```
class BagDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'ctx'
    model = Bag
    template_name = 'product_page.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = QuantityForm(initial={'quantity':1})
        context['Jackson'] = Bag.objects.get(title = 'Jackson')
        context['Anthony'] = Bag.objects.get(title = 'Anthony')
        return context
```

But the problem is the POST request. I cannot call the `render()` function because I have another view to handle the checkout, so I need to call `redirect()`. This is the code:

```
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = QuantityForm()
        b = Bag.objects.get(slug=kwargs['slug'])
        if form.is_valid:
            return redirect(b)# calls get_absolute_url which redirects to checkout/<slug>
```

And I cannot access the data that I'm posting in the other view. I think it's bad practise to post data like this to another view, but I couldn't come up with anything but that. Is there any other way to pass that data into the other view?

Note: I'm not using a cart system because I'm only dealing with two products.

Comment: There's a few options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters

Comment: That's a bit old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood correctly, maybe you can do something like this.

In the template for increasing quantity, you can put this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'add-to-checkout' order_item.item.slug %}"><i class="">INCREASE QUANTITY</i></a>
```

When the user clicks this, a function will be called:

```py
@login_required
def add_to_checkout(request, slug):
    #get the checkout  for this customer which is not fulfilled
    #increase the quantity
    #redirect to checkout page
```

Another idea can be using session. You can increase the amount in the detail page and save it to the sessions, then use in the checkout page.

I hope I have understood correctly your question.