# Django redirect with corrected optional url params

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement stackoverflow's url redirection using django / django rest framework, for example.
Say this url - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters`

As long as the question `pk (3209906)` is correct, stackov will automatically correct the `slug (django-return-redirect-with-parameters)`, even if you pass an incorrect slug.

My current code

views.py

```py
from django.db import models

class ArticleBody(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleBody
        read_only_fields = (
            "id",
            "title" 
            "slug"
        )
        fields = read_only_fields
```

views.py

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from .models import ArticleBody
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer

class ArticleView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, pk, slug=None):
        article_obj =  ArticleBody.objects.filter(id=pk).last()
        article = ArticleSerializer(article_obj).data

        if article:
            return Response({"article": article})

        return Response(
            {"message": "Article not found"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        )
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path

from .views import ArticleView

app_name = "article"

urlpatterns = [ 
    re_path(r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/$", ArticleView.as_view(), name="body"),
    re_path(
        r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", ArticleView.as_view(), name="body-slug"
    ),
]
```

Currently this code properly handles valid or invalid slugs. such as
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/1/`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/1/article-name/`
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/1/artic/` (incorrect slug)

Basically I am looking for a way to redirect all of these urls to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/1/article-name/`

Comment: you can do this with html5 replaceState https://stackoverflow.com/a/13451971/13773284 (propably stack is doing this, no history changes) or you can user redirect in django (not recommended as you hit db twice and you make history in browser)

Comment: Thanks, doing this in frontend makes more sense, I was in fact having issue with hitting db twice, when I tried to do this with a secondary view.