# Django redirect error unexpected keyword while returning to previous view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have searched and have not found any answers related to my specific problem.

When I submit a form from my `index` view to an `up_load` view and try to have the `up_load` view redirect back to the `index` view while including the `page` number as an argument, I get an error, I have tried using a `context` dictionary and still nothing.

**url.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'myApp'

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("", views.index, kwargs={'cliente_id': None}, name="index"),
    path("<int:cliente_id>/", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:cliente_id>/<str:page>", views.index, name="index"),
    path('up_load/', views.up_load, name='up_load'),
]
```

**views.py**

```py
def index(request, cliente_id=None):
    paginator = Paginator(client_list, 15)
    page_number = request.GET.get("page")
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {'cliente_id': cliente_id,
               'page': page,
               'paginator': paginator }
    return render(request, 'myApp/index.html', context)

def up_load(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExpeditensForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        cliente_id = request.POST.get('cliente_id', '/')
        page = request.POST.get('page', '/')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('myApp:index', cliente_id=cliente_id, page=page)
        else:
            pass
```

Django returns the following error.

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /Expedientes/4/1
Exception Value: index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'page'
```

- The browser shows the following URL:
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/Expedientes/4/1
- When it should be:
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/Expedientes/4/?page=1

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209906/django-return-redirect-with-parameters It might be helpful for you.

Comment: Use unique names to enable the possible reverse resolution of urls in code. See the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls

Answer (score 0):

Edit your function signature for this view to suppress the error

```
def index(request, cliente_id: int | None = None, page: str | None  = None):
    pass
```

Use unique names for your paths to enable the possible [reverse resolution of urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) in code.

Note: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Expedientes/4/?page=1 and http://127.0.0.1:8000/Expedientes/4/1 are two different paths. If you want to see http://127.0.0.1:8000/Expedientes/4/?page=1, then you have to pass parameters via [query parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) not [url parameters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/).